# Creating a function to check some combination of checks for auth

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to create a boolean auth function that takes in some combination of `*args` and `**kwargs` to enable auth checks. This particular function checks the user's group membership and admin status along with the usual permissions. Note that if a user is admin, they are allowed to bypass the permissions.

```py
def auth_check(request, org_group, *perms):
    if request.user not in User.objects.filter(groups__name__in=[org_group]):
        return False
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='admins').exists():
        return True
    for perm in perms:
        if request.user.has_perm(perm) == False:
            return False
    return True
```

My question is how do I make it so it is possible to pass in some `or` condition for the `*perms`. For example something like `'model.change_object' | 'model.remove_object'` like they do with [complex lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in Django.